# :after adjust height of parent

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a progress bar, and I am trying to adjust the height of the parent item based on the `content` of the `:after` pseudo element. Once you run the code, you will see that the `30%` is partially inside the div.

Is there a way for me to adjust the height of the element that the `:after` is attached to?

I tried changing the `display` property of the `:after` item but that didn't do anything.

```css
.pure-progress {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 10px;
}

.pure-progress>.pure-progress--bar {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  transition: width 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.pure-progress:after {
  position: absolute;
  height: inherit;
  line-height: 1.8rem;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  content: attr(data-progress);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="pure-progress" data-progress="30%">
  <div class="pure-progress--bar" style="width:30%"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change `absolute` to `relative` and add `display: block` - see demo below:

```css
.pure-progress {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 10px;
}

.pure-progress>.pure-progress--bar {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  transition: width 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.pure-progress:after {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  position: relative; /* ADDED */
  display: block; /* ADDED */
  height: inherit;
  line-height: 1.8rem;
  /*
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  */
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  content: attr(data-progress);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="pure-progress" data-progress="30%">
  <div class="pure-progress--bar" style="width:30%"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update the css of `.pure-progress:after` to

```
.pure-progress:after {
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  line-height: 1.8rem;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  content: attr(data-progress);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qmrsn762/)

**Update**

My answer does not work when the progress bar is overlapping the content text. Therefore it is necessary to position it using `position: relative` as suggested by kukkuz

The updated styles look like:

```
.pure-progress:after {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  line-height: 1.8rem;
  text-align: center;
  content: attr(data-progress);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

[Updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qmrsn762/2/)